# How to create an n sized array in c

Tags: c, initialization, declaration, variable-length-array

I am very new to C but I am having trouble on what seems a very trivial problem. All I am trying to do is create a n sized array, such that at the time of running I don't know its size and can't specify it. The following code works perfectly well.

```
int main()
{
        
    int LuhnsArray[15] = {0};

    for(int i = 0; i < 15; i++)
    {
        printf("%i ", LuhnsArray[i]);
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

However when I try and so something like this:

```
int main()
{
    
    int length = 15;
    
    int LuhnsArray[length] = {0};

    for(int i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {
        printf("%i ", LuhnsArray[i]);
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

Something which I would deem logical (something which I think would work in python for example) it comes up with an error attached. Could someone please point me in the right direction. Any chance of help from a newbie?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error is quite self-explanatory. Remove the initialization in definition:

```
int LuhnsArray[length]; /* = {0}; nope */
```

---

Instead, use `memset` if you want it zeroed out:

```
memset(LuhnsArray, 0, sizeof(LuhnsArray));
```

Note how `memset` takes byte size, which we can get conveniently for *an array* (but not for a pointer!) with `sizeof` operator.

---

Or just a for-loop:

```
for(int i = 0; i < length; i++)
{
    LuhnsArray[i] = 0;        
}
```

Answer (score 4):

As the error message says you may not initialize a variable length array in its declaration

```
int length = 15;

int LuhnsArray[length] = {0};
```

Note: A variable length array is an array the size of which is not specified with *integer constant expression*.

From the C Standard (6.7.9 Initialization)

> 3 The type of the entity to be initialized shall be an array of
> unknown size or a complete object type **that is not a variable length
> array type**

Instead you could write

```
#include <string.h>

//...

int length = 15;

int LuhnsArray[length];
memset( LuhnsArray, 0, sizeof( LuhnsArray ) );
```

Or instead of calling the function `memset` you could initialize the array in a loop as for example

```
for ( size_t i = 0; i < length; i++ )
{
    LuhnsArray[i] = 0;
}
```

Also you could allocate the array dynamically as for example

```
#include <stdlib.h>

//...

int length = 15;
int *LuhnsArray = malloc( length * sizeof( *LuhnsArray ) );
//..
```

or instead of `malloc` you could use `calloc` to zero initialize the array

```
#include <stdlib.h>

//...

int length = 15;
int *LuhnsArray = calloc( length, sizeof( *LuhnsArray ) );
//..
```

Pay also attention to that you may not declare a variable length array in a file scope. Variable length arrays must have automatic storage duration.

Answer (score 1):

The second snippet defines `LuhnsArray` as a variable-length array, meaning its size isn't determined until runtime.

Because of this, you may not use an initializer when you declare a VLA, because the size of the thing being initialized has to be known at *compile* time.

Similarly, a VLA may not be declared `static` or at file scope, since storage for such objects is allocated when the program is first loaded, even before `main` is executed.